# "java -version"in cmd gives no result

Tags: java, system-variable

I tried to install java 14 manually on Windows 10. I set the System Variables as in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeJxO.png).

But when I use the command "java -version" literally nothing happens...

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>java -version

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Something must be wrong, but I can't figure what...

Comment: You have both, some generic java ("....Oracle\Java\javapath") and the JDK in your PATH variable. Try to use only the JDK.

Comment: .. Or set the `bin` in `PATH` before the other one.

Comment: Damn both of that worked, Thanks!

Comment: have similar issue RESOLVE IT by writing in cmd "where java" and realize been decelerated twice in environment variables –

Comment: Take also a look at [JAVA command shows nothing in a command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70138145)…

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Move `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin\java` to the beginning in the `PATH` variable.
2. **Important** - Open a new `cmd` window and use the command `java -version`. Any already open `cmd` windows do not reflect the settings that you do in the environment variables form/window.

Answer (score 10):

## Solution

Please first run the following command

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin\java" --version
```

If that returns a result remove the following entries from your `PATH`

```
c:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin\java\bin
```

Then create an environment variable called `JAVA` and set it to `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`, then simply add `%JAVA%` to your `PATH` variable.

> You will need to close your command prompt window and reopen it before the change will take effect

Comment: Worked for me. I also had "...\Oracle\Java\javapath" in my PATH. Removing it from there solved it.