# JAVA command shows nothing in a command prompt

Tags: java, installation

My question is very simple but I still cannot find out what's the problem.
When I input `java`, `java -version` or `javac -version` in a command prompt nothing is shown at all: neither an "unknown file" error nor the result.

That's how it looks like:

[image: nothing is shown picture]

I used standard Java installer, PATH and JAVA_HOME variables were renewed.
I've set JDKs several times before but it's the first time I run into such a problem. Is there anything I am missing or is it a known bug?

Comment: Probably broken. Does uninstalling all java and reinstalling this one help?

Comment: Do you have another file on your path that is called `java`? Or maybe a java is on your path that is the wrong architecture? Can you specify the full path to your java installation?

Comment: @matt, I tried calling `java` from different directories, it didn't help. The installation dir is pretty much typical: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311. Of course, for PATH variable I add `\bin`.

Comment: You can specify the full path to run java.exe. Eg. "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\bin\java.exe". That will help you check if there is an issue with another java on your path. In linux there is a command 'which' that will let you see where the exe file you call resides.

Comment: "Of course, for PATH variable I add \bin" That doesn't sound correct. I suspect you mean the bin folder of the jdk is added to your path? Make sure it is escaped correctly and that nothing is on the path before your jdk that could have a broken java.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, reinstallation helped. It must indeed had been a kind of a problem with the installation process before.

Comment: As far as I remember, `java -version` writes to _STDERR_ (handle `2`) rather than _STDOUT_ (handle `1`); maybe this comes into play here…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this occasionally on Windows, and uninstalling all Java distributions (those with an installer) and reinstalling the one you need usually fixes it for me.

If you do a lot of Java development you may need to have several versions of Java available on your system to be sure that everything is compatible for a given project.  In that case, ZIP distributions that just need to be unpacked and not installed are very handy, especially with a good IDE that just needs to be told where to find them.

Answer (score -1):

Check you environment variables. Sometimes if your upgrade Java, the directory of your Java installation changes, but doesn't get updated in the environment variables. You'll you have to manual update them by correcting where they point to.